# calculated fields

Tags: calculated-column, datasheet

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I'm working on a List in a DataSheet view.

I created the field "Color" - a dropdown field that contains: "Yellow","Green","Blue".
I also created the fields: 
"YelloFruits" - a dropdown field that contains: "Banana","Lemon","Pineapple".
"GreenFruits - a dropdown field that contains: "Apple","Kiwi".
"BlueFruits - a dropdown field that contains: "Blueberries".

I need to create a calculated field to behave as follows:
IF the "Color" field is equal to "Yellow" THEN present the dropdown field "YellowFruits"
ELSE IF the "Color" field is equal to "Green" THEN present the dropdown field "GreenFruits"
ELSE IF the "Color" field is equal to "Blue" THEN present the dropdown field "BlueFruits".

Hope it is clear enough.

Thanks,
Dror.

Answer (score 2):

Calculated columns don't work that way.  Calculated columns set values based on information from other columns, not toggle visibility of form fields.  The closest thing I can think of that you're wanting to do is a cascade dropdown, filtered options in a drop down list based on the selection of a previous column.

The datasheet view cannot handle that to my knowledge, but if you create a single item New/Editform using the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) library, you can achieve that functionality with the [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) function and jQuery..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you want is possible. The DataSheet view is an build-in component (made available if the client has Access installed).

If you want special functionality (business logic) in your edit/new forms you have to roll your own.